# String and JSONArray are not display the same way in debugger

Tags: java, android, utf-8, android-studio

I am trying to understand the text difference I am getting while debugging in Android studio. It seems that the watcher is not able to show UTF-8 string. 
Here is the code :

```
    static public JSONArray CreateStationsJson(HttpEntity page) throws IOException, JSONException
{
    String getText = EntityUtils.toString(page, HTTP.UTF_8);
    JSONArray js = new JSONArray(getText);
    return js;
}
```

And here are the watch result if I put a break point on the return statement:

-getText :`[{"id":"1","meteomediaID":"caqc1304","snow1":"Pr\u00e8s de 5 cm"`...

-js : `[{"id":"1","meteomediaID":"caqc1304","snow1":"Près de 5 cm"`...

You can note that the json displays correctly the accent but the string doesn't. What is the reason behind that ?
If I try to display them on the phone the string still appear with the \u00e8, is there a way to remove that and have the accent è appears ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think Android Studio not accurate when showing UTF-8 strings.

Comment: I get the same thing while displaying the text on the phone.

Comment: Can i ask you what do you want to know ?. 
this line String getText = EntityUtils.toString(page, HTTP.UTF_8);// encode the string to UTF-8 so "è" become "\u00e8"

Comment: it should not be the opposite ? it should not convert \u00e8 to "è" ? In that case how to get that conversion ?